# Angular 2- Subscribe is not a function error

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am trying to subscribe from a service, it builds without error but I get the error "this.myService.getAll is not a function" when viewing in the browser.

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from "@angular/http";


@Injectable()

export class MyServiceService {

  url:string;

  constructor(private http:Http) {
    this.url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/scrumboard";
  }

  public getAll(): any {
    let result = this.http.get(this.url+"/lists");
    return result;
  }
}
```

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { MyServiceService } from '../my-service.service';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './full-layout.component.html'
})
export class FullLayoutComponent {

  public disabled: boolean = false;
  public status: {isopen: boolean} = {isopen: false};

  public toggled(open: boolean): void {
    console.log('Dropdown is now: ', open);
  }

  public toggleDropdown($event: MouseEvent): void {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    this.status.isopen = !this.status.isopen;
  }

  constructor(public myService:MyServiceService) {

  }
  public subscribe() {
    this.myService.getAll().subscribe(
      (data: Response) => console.log(data)
    );
  }
}
```

Finally the app.module.ts:

```
providers: [{
    provide: MyServiceService,
    useClass: HashLocationStrategy,
  }],
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using Angular 2? There seems to be nothing wrong judging from the code you provided, except I consider Angular 2 still beta. Upgrade to 5? Then you can also use the new HttpClient instead of Http ( https://angular.io/guide/http )

Comment: in your service the getAll just return the http request without using result, also in your module for the component have you added the service to its providers

Comment: Try this: in the constructor of your component inject the service as: ``constructor(private myService:MyServiceService)`` and in ``ngOnInit`` of your component call ``this.subscribe()``, your service has to be added in the service section of ``@NgModule`` as well, in the list of providers.

Comment: Thank you for your answers but still the same error! and i updated my post to add the providers.

Comment: Why are you using ``HashLocationStrategy`` in place of your own service ? your provider section should be ``providers: [MyServiceService]`` no ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare your provider as:

```
providers: [
    MyServiceService
]
```

Because you are using `HashLocationStrategy` class in place of your service class, and `HashLocationStrategy` don't have `getAll` function.

Another thing is to inject your service as private:

```
constructor(private myService:MyServiceService)
```

And call that `subscribe` function you added from [ngOnInit](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit)

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.subscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is bad decision to name method like subscribe() because it could confused you and another developer, it is better to name it like:

```
public subscribetoGetAll(...;
```

Your solution is to call this mehod in a constructor or ngOnInit (it is better to do in ngOnInit):

```
export class FullLayoutComponent, OnInit {

  public disabled: boolean = false;
  public status: {isopen: boolean} = {isopen: false};

  public toggled(open: boolean): void {
    console.log('Dropdown is now: ', open);
  }

  public toggleDropdown($event: MouseEvent): void {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    this.status.isopen = !this.status.isopen;
  }

  constructor(private myService:MyServiceService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() { // ngOnInit added
    this.subscribetoGetAll();  // <-- here you calling your method
  }


  public subscribetoGetAll() {
    this.myService.getAll().subscribe(
      (data: Response) => console.log(data)
    );
  }
}
```